# How can I fork a repository into an old destination?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have a repository I have already forked once into a destination. Let's call that destination **forkedRepo**. Let's call the repository I am forking **sourceRepo**.

I want to fork **sourceRepo** into **forkedRepo** a second time, overwriting the contents of **forkedRepo**. The reason for this is that there have been so many changes to **sourceRepo** since the initial fork.

I think it's sloppy to delete **forkedRepo** and then recreate **forkedRepo**. Is there a way to overwrite **forkedRepo** with the contents of **sourceRepo**?

This is a question pertaining to Github. I am forking a Github repository (**sourceRepo**) into a repository that already exists (**forkedRepo**), and this is the second time I am performing the fork operation.

Comment: What exactly is "sloppy" about doing the simple, obvious thing? If what you want is a clean start, that will provide it.

Comment: github allows fork syncing with `force` flag, at least from the [cli](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/syncing-a-fork#syncing-a-fork-with-the-github-cli).